# Java : Remove empty columns in Resultset

Tags: java

How can I remove empty columns from a Resultsets or DataList?

For example : I run a query then the SQL returns a Resultset

```
Name    Age    Address    Telephone
----    ---    -------    ---------
Zed      23               12345456
Charlo   25               53232323
```

How can I remove the empty column "Address" in the Resultset?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: selecting only Name, Age and  Telephone if the Address column is always not set, if sometimes it is set, then you have to handle the null.

Comment: If the address is always empty, don't select it.

Comment: But the problem is we don't know which column will be all null before the query.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers... ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You tell SQL what columns you want in the query, and it gives you all the columns you asked for.

Comment: The columns are dynamically defined by the user together with the filters in the where clause, so I need to build the query which before the execution I have no idea which column will have empty data. Using "NOT NULL" clause eliminates the rows with empty value in a column but not necessary means that that column are empty. So I need to remove the empty columns from the ResultSet after the query.

Comment: @sprenna you'll have to do it on the java side.

Answer (score 0):

If the Address is always empty, or is not required, then just change the query that generates the `ResultSet`. For example, your query would be something like...

```
SELECT Name, Age, Telephone FROM Table;
```

Otherwise, if some of the entries have an Address, you will need to detect the empty values when you loop through them in your `ResultSet`.

You can also change your query to only return results with an Address, such as this...

```
SELECT Name, Age, Address, Telephone FROM Table WHERE Address IS NOT NULL;
```

You can't know in advance whether an entire column is empty - you have to loop over each entry in your `ResultSet` to detect it, or write a count query like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(Address) FROM Table WHERE Address IS NOT NULL;
```

This will return `0` if there are no addresses. You can use this on your other columns too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the column from the query if it's always null, but you can exclude all NULL values from the object you map the `ResultSet` into.  (You don't pass `ResultSet` out of the persistence tier, do you?)

Answer (score 0):

If the column is always empty, then, as others have noted, just remove it from the SELECT clause on the query. If you're using "SELECT *", don't. It's a bad practice. You could be processing all sorts of unused data. If a SELECT * picks up one unnecessary 5-byte field, no big deal I suppose. But even if that's all it's doing now, next week you or someone else might add a 50k BLOB field to the record, and then to get the 50 bytes you need you're also processing 50k you don't need.

If you mean that after you get the ResultSet you discover that the column is always blank or null, so what? You have to read the data to discover this. The fact that a column is in your ResultSet does not force anything about what you display on the screen. If you want to eliminate the column from a display, you can do this in code.